# Python Beautiful Soup Scraping & Parsing

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There is a Java Script page I am attempting to scrape with BeautifulSoup

```
bb2_addLoadEvent(function() {
    for ( i=0; i < document.forms.length; i++ ) {
        if (document.forms[i].method == 'post') {
            var myElement = document.createElement('input');
            myElement.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            myElement.name = 'bb2_screener_';
            myElement.value = '1568090530 122.44.202.205 122.44.202.205';
            document.forms[i].appendChild(myElement);
        }
```

I would like to obtain the value of "myElement.value", but I am not familiar with how to do so( If it is even possible with BeautifulSoup)

Ive tried :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(a.text, 'html.parser')
h = soup.find('type')   ...('div') ... ('input') ... even ('var')
    print(soup)
```

and NO Luck :(

Is there a way of obtaining the value?  If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to know more about the myElement.value across different pages. You might get away with a simple character set and lead string as shown in regex below. I would like to tighten it up but would need more examples ..... perhaps those number lengths are fixed and repeating ?  ..... then something like `p = re.compile(r"myElement\.value = '(\d{10}(?:(\s\d{3}\.\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}){2}))';")` <= then take group 1.

```
import re

s = '''bb2_addLoadEvent(function() {
    for ( i=0; i < document.forms.length; i++ ) {
        if (document.forms[i].method == 'post') {
            var myElement = document.createElement('input');
            myElement.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            myElement.name = 'bb2_screener_';
            myElement.value = '1568090530 122.44.202.205 122.44.202.205';
            document.forms[i].appendChild(myElement);
        }'''

p = re.compile(r"myElement\.value = '([\d\s\.]+)';")
print(p.findall(s)[0])
```

---

@SIM also kindly proposed:

```
p = re.compile(r"value[^']+'([^']*)'"
```

Comment: How about `re.compile(r"value[^']+'([^']*)'")`? It seems I'm beginning to learn regex.

Comment: @QHarr thanks .  Your example worked perfectly.  For anyone who was stuck with the same issue as me I made a get request and used the .text of the get , then used “QHarr’s” example to obtain the value.

Answer (score 0):

If `myElement.value =` is static, this can be achieved with a simple regular expression:

```
value = re.compile(r"myElement\.value = '([^']+)'").search(str).group(1)
```

This matches `myElement.value = '`, followed by non-`'` characters, followed by another `'`, where all the non-`'` characters are captured in a group. Then the `group(1)` extracts the group from the match.

If the string may contain escaped `'`s as well, eg:

```
myElement.value = 'foo \' bar';
```

then alternate `\.` with `[^']`:

```
myElement\.value = '((?:\\.|[^'])+)'
```

https://regex101.com/r/Tdarel/1